# Отменить сохранение записи save_post

Tags: php, wordpress

Как отменить обновление записи, если валидация не прошла?
Допустим нужно отредактировать заказ `woocommerce` или запись блога, использую такой код:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'admin_save_order', 10, 1 );
function admin_save_order( $post_id ) {
    if ( 'shop_order' == $_POST[ 'post_type' ] ) {
        if ( current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            if(not validate){
            return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

что-то типа такого как правильно сделать? и нужно добавить какое-то сообщение для админа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте фильтр `wp_insert_post_empty_content`. Пример:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_empty_content', 'cancel_order_save_function', 99, 2 );
function cancel_order_save_function( $maybe_empty, $postarr ) {
    if ( true === wp_is_post_revision( $postarr[ 'ID' ] ) ) {
       return $maybe_empty; //do not forget to return original value to keep other filters working
    }

    if( not validate ) {
        return true;
    }

    return $maybe_empty; //do not forget to return original value to keep other filters working
}
```